# how to set same path to parent and iframe site

Tags: javascript, laravel, iframe

I have a website built with node. I wrap it by built user registration with PHP Laravel. I will merge the first website in the second by using `<iframe>`

How can I set the path -end of URL- of URL for parent site and `<iframe>` the same? I mean if the URL of first `<iframe>` site is "first.com/blogs/99" I need that the URL of parent site is "parent.com/blogs/99".

Comment: sounds like you want to update [iframe.src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-src)

Comment: @sphinx yes i want to update iframe.src and change the a.herf inside the frame